# iPhone: Background Listener

Tags: iphone

Is there any background listener in iPhone SDK ? Which I can register in viewDidLoad and unregister in viewDIdUnload...A listener, that I can say something to do at any time ? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at NSNotification and NSNotificationCenter.  You can also do Key Value Observing to make functions that respond to variable changes.